# Angular Harness - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locatorForOptional')

Tags: angular, testing, typeerror, karma-runner

I am writing tests in Angular, Karma with Harness but i do not have material in my app.
My HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="headerOK">
    <table-filter
        *ngIf="display_tableHeader.hasGlobalFilter"
        #filter
        placeholder="Search filter..."
        (filterChange)="onGlobalFilterChange($event)"
    ></table-filter>
    <ng-container
        *ngIf="display_tableHeader.hasStandAloneFilter"
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="filterStandAlone"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ display_tableHeader: display_tableHeader, filterForm: filterForm }"
    >
</ng-container>
    ...
```

in my table.component.harness.ts i have:

```
import { BaseHarnessFilters, ComponentHarness, HarnessPredicate } from '@angular/cdk/testing';

interface TableHarnessOptions extends BaseHarnessFilters {
    /** Filters based on the trigger text for the menu. */
    triggerText?: string | RegExp;
}

export class TableHarness extends ComponentHarness {
    static hostSelector = 'table';
    public selectFilterContainer = this.locatorForOptional('#filter');

    static with(options: TableHarnessOptions): HarnessPredicate<TableHarness> {
        return new HarnessPredicate(TableHarness, options);
    }
}
```

finally spec.ts:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ListComponent, TableModule } from './list.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TableHarness } from './table.component.harness';
import { HarnessLoader } from '@angular/cdk/testing';
import { TestbedHarnessEnvironment } from '@angular/cdk/testing/testbed';

describe('ListComponent', () => {
    let component: ListComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListComponent>;
    let tableHarness: TableHarness;
    let loader: HarnessLoader;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(), TableModule],
            declarations: [ListComponent],
            providers: [TableHarness]
        }).compileComponents();
    });
    beforeEach(async () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        tableHarness = await TestBed.inject(TableHarness);
        loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    });
    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should create the TableComponentHarness', () => {
        expect(tableHarness).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

but i get following error:

```
Chrome Headless 114.0.5735.90 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ListComponent should create the TableComponentHarness FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locatorForOptional')
```

and i really do not have any idea why?
Also would like to locate the ng-container but from what i have found on internet, it is not DOM element, thus it cannot be selected